# Adding my own custom woocommerce shortcode to child theme, how?

Tags: shortcode, plugins

So I bought a theme at themeforest.com that has some custom templates to use with the Woocommerce plugin. I made a child theme so I don't have to edit anything in this original theme.

What I was able to do so far is overwrite the form-login.php template in my child theme.

What I'm trying to do now is add a custom shortcode, similar to the [woocommerce_my_account] one that will call the form-login.php template that I've overwritten.

The code that creates the shortcodes in the Woocommerce plugin looks like this:

File: /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/class-wc-shortcodes.php

```
class WC_Shortcodes {

    public function __construct() {
        add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_my_account', array( $this, 'my_account' ) );
    }

    public function my_account( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        return $woocommerce->shortcode_wrapper( array( 'WC_Shortcode_My_Account', 'output' ), $atts );
    }
}
```

File: /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-my-account.php

```
class WC_Shortcode_My_Account {

    public static function get( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        return $woocommerce->shortcode_wrapper( array( __CLASS__, 'output' ), $atts );
    }

    public static function output( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

            woocommerce_get_template( 'myaccount/form-login.php' );

        } else {

            extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                    'order_count' => 5
            ), $atts ) );

            woocommerce_get_template( 'myaccount/my-account.php', array(
                'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() ),
                'order_count'   => 'all' == $order_count ? -1 : $order_count
            ) );

        }
    }
}
```

How could I add a custom shortcode like that one?

Do I put it in my child theme?

Can I just copy/paste the code from the output function, put it in my functions.php and do add_shortcode('custom_shortcode', 'function_in_my_functions_php'); ? But what about the global variable $woocommerce? Can I access that variable from within my child theme?

Thank you so much if anyone wants to shed some light on this, I'm just starting to learn Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global `$woocommerce` can be reached, you just have to write `global $woocommerce;` before using it. Read [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables).

You can define your own shortcode, see [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). You can copy/paste the code because it's wrapped in a class so it won't trigger fatal error due to double declaration.

But shortcode do not work that way :

```
function shortcode_handler($atts) {
  //code goes here
 }
add_shortcode('name_of_shortcode','shortcode_handler');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, works perfectly, didn't know it was that simple.